# How to move item from one list to another list by button click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build two list at where item can be moved from one list to another list. I have found [this by searching](http://www.bootply.com/126254). But, I don't need multiple selection and checkboxes. That's why, I am trying to simplify it with my own way. But, I cannot make it completely as I am not so good at jQuery.

My Sample code:

```
<ul class="list-group source">
   <li class="list-group-item">Option 1</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Option 2</li>
</ul>

<button class="add" disabled="disabled"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
<button class="remove" disabled="disabled"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>

<ul class="list-group destination">
</ul>
```

I manly want two set of things at there:

(1)
(a) when no item is selected at source, keep 'add' button(which is for moving item from source to destination) disabled. I have added this code which is not working:

```
var source = $('.source').children('.active');
    if(source.length > 0) {
        $(this).attr('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('disabled',true);
    };
```

(b) when no item is selected at destination, keep 'remove' button(which is for moving item from  destination to source) disabled. I have wrote similar code like above which is not working too.

(2) (a) when clicking on 'add' button, move selected item of source to destination. To do this, I have write something like this, but I don't know what should I write for moving item:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    var item = $('.source').children('.active');
    // Move item from source to destination when one item is active/selected
    if(item.length > 0) {

    }
});
```

(b) when clicking on 'remove' button, move selected item of destination to source. To do this, I have to do same thing as previous.

Please, help me for making this successfully. [Here is the fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/8xszm70d/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you meant but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/8xszm70d/4/

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(){ 
    // add active class at list-item by click
    $(this).parent().find('.list-group-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // make add(>) button disabled untill selecting one
    var source = $(this).parents('.pick-list').find('.source').children('.active');
    if(source.length > 0) {
        $(this).attr('disabled',false);
        $('.add').attr('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        $('.add').attr('disabled',true);
    };

    // make remove(<) button disabled untill selecting one
    var des = $(this).parents('.pick-list').find('.destination').children('.active');
    if(des.length > 0) {
        $(this).attr('disabled',false);
        $('.remove').attr('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        $('.remove').attr('disabled',true);
    };
});

$('.add').click(function(){
    var item = $(this).parents('.pick-list').find('.source').children('.active');
    // Move item from source to destination when one item is active/selected
    if(item.length > 0) {
        $('.source .list-group-item.active').appendTo('.list-group.destination');
        $('.add').attr('disabled',true);
        $('.destination .list-group-item.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});

$('.remove').click(function(){
    var item = $(this).parents('.pick-list').find('.destination').children('.active');
    // Move item from destination to source when one item is active/selected
    if(item.length > 0) {
        $('.destination .list-group-item.active').appendTo('.source');
        $('.remove').attr('disabled',true);
        $('.source .list-group-item.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want. But, there is a little problem. those two buttons should be disabled until selecting any. This is good at the time of page loading at your fiddle. After selecting one from source, 'add' button is enabling. This is fine too. After finishing of moving that selecting item from source to destination by the 'add' button, add button should be disable again as then no item is selected any more at source. Same needed for 'remove' button too.